# MSI installer - invoke PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I have a blocker in MSI installer package creation, please find the below details and let me know if any solutions,

I have written PowerShell script to automate the Hyper-V virtual machine provision ( AWS i3.metal instance type ) and the script is working fine.

I wants that PowerShell script as MSI installer package
Working in visual studio 2017 community version to make MSI installer package
For that I used WIX installer commands and created wxs file to make MSI

Successfully created MSI installer using WIX but while installing that MSI, it’s not invoking PowerShell script

But I could see that application installed ( listed in control panel & installation folder is created in C:\programFiles)

Used wix SetProperty, CustomAction & InstallExecuteSequence cmd but no luck with invoking Powershell script

This is for a new Windows server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="19fe6e20-a840-4829-8883-bde0bfa51d4c" Name="testing" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="muni" UpgradeCode="93008c8b-adb9-4498-8be2-4a83162b3a35">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="test" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Source="C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\testMSI\test\Invoke-Test.ps1" Id="InvokeTestPS1"  />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="testing" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Guid="*">
        <File Id="InvokeTestPS1" Source="Invoke-Test.ps1" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE">
      <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLEXE"
                      Type="raw"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell"
                      Name="Path" />
    </Property>
    <Condition Message="This application requires Windows PowerShell.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR POWERSHELLEXE]]>
    </Condition>

    <SetProperty Id="InvokeTestPS1"
             Before="InstallFinalize"
             Sequence="execute"
             Value ="&quot;[POWERSHELLEXE]&quot; -Version 2.0 -NoProfile -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command &quot;&amp; '[#InvokeTestPS1]' ; exit $$($Error.Count)&quot;" />
    <CustomAction Id="InvokeTestPS1"
                  BinaryKey="WixCA"
                  DllEntry="WixSilentExec"
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="yes" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="InvokeTestPS1" After="InstallFinalize">
        <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
      </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <Feature Id="Application" Title="Minefold" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
    </Feature>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

MSI installer should invoke Powershell script - Means once i created MSI then i need to install that MSI and MSI need to invoke the powershell script

Comment: Provisioning VMs doesn't sound like a good task for an installer package.  I'd be tempted to do it the other way around - have a script that creates the VMs, then invokes the MSI to install the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my requirement is MSI installer needs to invoke powershell script